# Goodies to introduce on JUGs

Tags: guava

Are there any goodies/statistics/logos/etc. that we can use to present/introduce Guava (power point) on JUGs ?

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.appbrain.com/stats/libraries/details/guava/google-guava quotes some statistics on Guava's users in the Android App Store.

That said, I don't think we've devoted that much effort to collecting e.g. lists of companies that use Guava.  Maybe that's a thing we should do.

Comment: Thx. Are there any logo we can use ?

Comment: That said, I should also mention http://www.sonatype.com/people/2012/05/google-guava-shows-strong-growth-in-april/ -- as I understand it, that's based on the total number of downloads from the Maven repositories.